# how to obtain raw URL path in rust?

Tags: parsing, url, path

Let's say I have the URL:

`http://host/path/to/../some/thing`

I want to parse the URL and get the raw/untouched path string:

`/path/to/../some/thing`

Using, url::Url, I can do:

```
let url = url::Url::parse("http://host/path/to/../some/thing").unwrap();
println!("{}", url.path());
```

But this gives a normalized version of the path:

```
/path/some/thing
```

url::Url  is doing more than I want it to do.  (It also percent encodes things.)

Some other langs make it easy, for example in PHP, I can just do:

```
$ php -r 'echo parse_url( "http://host/path/to/../some/thing" )["path"] . "\n";'
/path/to/../some/thing
```

So, can anyone point me towards another URL parsing crate that can do this, and is known to be solid/tested?